# Is using Quadrature Demod for MFSK demodulation a good idea?

Tags: gnuradio, fsk

I'm experimenting with MFSK in gnuradio, and seem to be quite successful simply using:

1. quadrature demod on the raw data to get the frequencies
2. RRC filter
3. clock sync on that
4. Constellation decoder with four custom constellation points all around the real axis

This seems to work for me. But is it a dead end? Will I get much better performance using FFT or a Goertzel filter per frequency?

It seems to me that my approach is more friendly to frequency lock after the quadrature demod, than an FFT with buckets slightly misaligned to the signal, or Goertzel filters just slightly off.

So question: Is my approach bad (worse at receiving weak or distorted signals), or a good idea?

I'm not concerned with CPU efficiency of my approach, though it may be better?

Comment: Yes absolutely using IQ demod over FFT for MFSK. Not sure on choice of RRC filter… was the MFSK transitions done with an RRC filter? The matched filter should match the transitions.

Comment: I don't know of anything that uses RRC with MSK pulses.  GMSK for limiting spectrum use is far more common.  BTW, I've found that this phase coherent demodulation with polyester (3 bit) matched filters and viterbi decoding has excellent performance: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241629765_Coherent_demodulation_of_AIS-GMSK_signals_in_co-channel_interference .  Implementation in GNURadio requires all custom written blocks.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I used a simple VCO with instant shifts on the TX side for now (then LPF). RRC seemed to work well for me after tuning number of taps. But now I know that this filter is the "weird" part of my reception, and otherwise seems sane. Thanks!

Comment: If either of you elevate the comment to an answer I can give the tick.